# Angular2: Is it possible to use custom types in html templates?

Tags: angular, typescript

For example I have an enumeration

```
export enum CustomPages{
  page1 = 1,
  page2 = 2,
  page3 = 3
}
```

In html template I want to access this enum.

For example:

```
<a class="nav-link" [class.active]="page == CustomPages.page1" href="#">Categories and responses</a>
```

It throws an exception

> Cannot read property 'page1' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `CustomPages` inside your component.

```
import {CustomPages} from 'path/to/enum/CustomPages';

@Component({...})
export class YourComponentName {

    CustomPages = CustomPages; // <- assign enum to the same name as a field.

    constructor(..){..}

    ...

}
```

Comment: Ha ha, perfect)) Thank you)