# How to pass enum via angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have component0 and component1. component1 is child component of component0.
On the typescript on component0's code I have a enum "Worker" that have "A" and "B".On component0 template(html) I have selector that apply component1 
see like that:

```
<sel> </sel>
```

I want to pass a type of enum from the template  that on component1 I can check witch value I got.

for example:

```
<sel [Worker]=Worker.A> </sel>
```

and on component 1 (after I get the vale on @input)
do a switch case on the value and check if I got A/B

How can I do this please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Is it possible to use custom types in html templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244029/angular2-is-it-possible-to-use-custom-types-in-html-templates)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the enum type into the local scope and reference it that way.  Types are not available in your view otherwise.

Try this:

```
export class Component0 {
   public enumType: Worker;
}
```

Then you can use it in the view:

```
<sel [Worker]="enumType.A"> </sel>
```